# CakePHP function isAuthorized

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am following instructions directly from Cakebook to hide certain things from a common user on my administrative system. Thus it would be possible only the administrator to access all pages. However, I am unable to run any user who accesses can see all. The following code:

```
public function beforeFilter(){
    $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Form' => array(
        'userModel' => 'Usuario',
        'fields' => array(
            'username' => 'login',
            'password' => 'senha')));
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array(
        'controller' => 'usuarios',
        'action' => 'login');


    parent::beforeFilter();
}

    public function isAuthorized($user) {
    if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin') {
        return true; 
    }
    return false; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but I'll give it a try.

I have cleaned your code, made some indents and more readable (for me at least). I also removed `parent::beforeFilter();`. **AppController.php:**

```
public function beforeFilter(){
    // You don't need this line: parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Form' => array(
        'userModel' => 'Usuario',
        'fields' => array(
            'username' => 'login',
            'password' => 'senha'
            )
        )
    );
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array(
        'controller' => 'usuarios',
        'action' => 'login'
    );
}

public function isAuthorized($user) {
    if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin') {
        return true; 
    }
    return false; 
}
```

Now only users with the admin role can access your pages. If you want any user to have access to post comments, this is an example of how to let him. **CommentsController.php:**

```
    public function isAuthorized($user) {
    // All registered users can add comment
    if ($this->action === 'add') {
      return true;
    }

    return parent::isAuthorized($user);
}
```

Now admins can view every single page, but a registered user can only see *app/comments/add*